# Как освободить использованный для BitmapImage файл?

Tags: c#

Нужно освободить файл `1.jpg` для записи после того как `BitmapImage` начал работу с другим файлом.

Вот код

```
using System;
using System.Drawing; //в ссылке System.Drawing
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;//в ссылке PresentationCore

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BitmapImage img;

            img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\img\1.jpg"));
            //Несмотря на переход к 2.jpg, файл 1.jpg остается занят 
            img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\img\2.jpg"));
            Image i = Image.FromFile(@"D:\img\3.jpg");

            Console.WriteLine(@"Try write in D:\img\1.jpg");
            Console.ReadKey();
            i.Save(@"D:\img\1.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в особенности поведения. Немного другой вариант решения:

```
public static ImageSource BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.UriSource = source;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    return bitmap;
}
```

После создание файл будет сразу закрыт.

Ссылки по теме:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b2270cb-f182-4f5f-a6c6-c78dfe4e3230/how-to-dispose-a-systemwindowsmediaimagesource?forum=wpf
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319447/release-handle-on-file-imagesource-from-bitmapimage

Comment: Понятно почему я не смог сам найти ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Стоит добавить `bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;`. Тогда можно будет повторно подгрузить файл под тем же именем, но уже измененным содержимым.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте проинициализировать рисунок иначе:

```
var stream = File.OpenRead(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\1.jpg");
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    stream.Close();
```

После закрытия потока файл будет разблокирован.

Comment: Спасибо, решение работает. Но у меня не получается заменить содержимое `BitmapImage` во второй раз. Можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: bitmap.Dispose();